# How to encrypt hard disk?

Tags: security, microsoft

Can I encrypt hard disks? If yes, then how? Can it be used for any individual drive or I will have to encrypt all at once?

Comment: Hi There! can you more specific as to whether internal or external disks? or both? Your question is partly completed. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
sudo modprobe dm_crypt
```

For more info, visit [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto)

Comment: A more thorough and detailed explanation would have been nice. Most of your answer relies on that link.

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure where you are at with your Ubuntu installation (existing, or just starting).
Easiest is to encrypt your full drive at installation time, as [here](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/11/privacy-ubuntu-1210-full-disk-encryption). If you have multiple drives, you can encrypt the additional drives later. [Here](https://davidyat.es/2015/04/03/encrypting-a-second-hard-drive-on-ubuntu-14-10-post-install/) is a nice writeup that describes how to encrypt additional drives, such that they will be unlocked when you decrypt your login drive. I can attest it worked fine for me with Ubuntu 15.10.